# How to fetch all in orm symfony?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, query-builder

I'm trying to get all the list of Users query

```
$userList = [1,5,2,3,1];
$users = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findBy(['id' => $userList]);
```

this code is working but the it distinct the user. It display like this

```
---------------
userid  |  name
---------------
1       |  we
5       |  ace
2       |  red
3       |  ran
```

but i want to display like this one

```
---------------
userid  |  name
---------------
1       |  we
5       |  ace
2       |  red
3       |  ran
1       |  we
```

How can i do that in ORM?

**Update**

I try this one.

```
public function getUsers($id)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->addSelect('u')
            ->distinct(false)
            ->where('u.id IN (:ulist)')
            ->setParameter('ulist', $id)
            ->getQuery();
        $users = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

        return $users;
    }
```

but it display the same

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the query builder.

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
->select('u')
->where('u.id IN (:ulist)')
->setParameter('ulist', $userList)
->getQuery();
$users = $query->getResult();
```

if this still gets you distinct results try this

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
->select('u')
->distinct(false)
->where('u.id IN (:ulist)')
->setParameter('ulist', $userList)
->getQuery();
$users = $query->getResult();
```

Otherwise you'll have to create an array of objects. You can do it by replacing the last line with

```
$users = $query->getResult(Query:HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Now you have a multidimensional array with all records, and you can display them as many want as you want just fetching them like $users[0]['username'] for example

Comment: I got same result. It distinct. I change the getDoctrine() function to getEntityManager(). Does this will matter in my code?

Comment: I change the getDoctrine() function to getEntityManager() because In my User repository getDoctrine() not found

Comment: Are you in a controller? If you're in a controller this code is perfectly valid, at least in symfony 3+. You tried even the second query?

Comment: I'm in User repository.

Comment: if you're in user Repository and are extending EntityRepository, remove the first line of the code, and then change the second like this: $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')

Comment: I got same result again. I think this will not work in mysql

Comment: Do you need to display that table? In this case I have a solution for you

Comment: Yes but now for you is much easier to display the same record just typing $users[1]['username'] for example